# Intercepting method with Spring AOP using only annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop

In my Spring context file I have something like this:

```
<bean id="userCheck" class="a.b.c.UserExistsCheck"/>
<aop:config>
      <aop:aspect ref="userCheck">
         <aop:pointcut id="checkUser"
                expression="execution(* a.b.c.d.*.*(..)) &amp;&amp; args(a.b.c.d.RequestObject)"/>
         <aop:around pointcut-ref="checkUser" method="checkUser"/>
      </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

a.b.c.UserExistsCheck looks like this:

```
@Aspect
public class UserExistsCheck {

@Autowired
private UserInformation userInformation;

public Object checkUser(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    int userId = ... //get it from the RequestObject passed as a parameter
    if (userExists(userId)) {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } else {
        return new ResponseObject("Invalid user);
    }
}
```

And the class that is being intercepted with this stuff looks like this:

```
public class Klazz {
    public ResponseObject doSomething(RequestObject request) {...}
}
```

This works. UserExistCheck is executed as desired before the call is passed to Klazz. The problem is that this is the only way I got it working. To get this working by using annotations instead of the context file seems to be just too much for my small brain. So... how exactly should I annotate the methods in UserExistsCheck and Klazz? And do I still need something else too? Another class? Still something in the context file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you enabled annotation-based AOP? The [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aspectj-support) says you have to add

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

to your spring configuration. Then you need to add an annotation in front of your `checkUser` method. It looks like you want `@Around` advice, as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice).

```
@Aspect
public class UserExistsCheck {

  @Around("execution(* a.b.c.d.*.*(..)) && args(a.b.c.d.RequestObject)")
  public Object checkUser(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
```

Comment: Yes, I have enabled <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> from the beginning. I tried this as well, but doesn't work, the checkUser method is never called :(

Comment: Actually this _did_ work, I just had a stupid mistake in the args, thanks! Now I wonder what I did wrong originally before trying the context file approach...

Answer (score 3):

From the example code you've provided, it appears that you're trying to create advice for a class that doesn't implement any interfaces.  As described in the [Proxying Mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying) section of the Spring docs, if you're going to do this, you'll need to enable CGLIB:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

I've personally found this to be a bit more finicky than the documentation indicates it should be, and though it does work if all of the stars are aligned just right, it's often easier--and preferable from a design standpoint--to declare your AOP advice on an interface, as follows.  (Note that you'll need to obtain your instance of `KlazzImpl` from your `BeanFactory`/`ApplicationContext`.)

```
public interface Klazz {
  ResponseObject doSomething(RequestObject request);
}

public class KlazzImpl implements Klazz {
  public ResponseObject doSomething(RequestObject request) {...}
}
```

Additionally, your use of the `args` expression is a little bit off.  See the following:

```
@Aspect
public class UserExistsCheck {
  @Autowired
  private UserInformation userInformation;

  @Around("execution(* a.b.c.d.*.*(..)) && args(reqObj)")
  public Object checkUser(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, a.b.c.d.RequestObject reqObj) throws Throwable {
      // ...
  }
}
```

These changes should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, actually Klazz does implement an interface but I'm using Spring autowiring for creating the instance. Sorry for not informing about this, I thought it's not relevant. Anyway all the info is useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

since spring 3.1 add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` to your `@Configuraiton`